# The probability for a random walk to return to the origin?

Tags: probability

The question is like the following,

> A computer program is randomly generating $m$ $0$s and $n$ $1$s, where $m>n>0$. The generation is one digit at a time, and the sequence is recorded every time when a new digit is generated.
>
> What is the probability that at least one recorded binary sequence has the same number of $0$s and $1$s?

I think this is like a random walk. A particle starts at origin, and when a $0$ is generated, the particle goes up, when a $1$ is generated, the particle goes down. Then the question is actually asking for the probability of the particle returning to origin.

Anyone can probide some help or reference how to solve such problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to the [Ballot problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem), which says that the probability that you always have strictly more 0s than 1s is $\frac{m-n}{m+n}$. So the probability that at some point they are equal is $$\frac{2n}{m+n}\cdot$$ Note that since $m>n$, the number of 1s cannot be always strictly larger than the number of 0s.